# What is this symbol consisting of a horizontal line crossed by a rotated vertial line?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm looking at the following symbol, between W and X, in an old PDF file:

[image: bar cross]

and would like to use it in Math mode in my document, but can't figure it out which symbol it is. Is it a standard Math symbol? Any suggestions for symbols that look similar to it?

The PDF file is here: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=74833, though it's not open access.
The title of the paper is: "Scannerless NSLR(1) parsing of programming languages"

Comment: Do you happen to know the context of this excerpt? If so, please elaborate

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: this could possibly be the unicode symbol `233F` -- "apl functional symbol slash bar", although for that symbol, the slash is a lot longer.  (the version with the backslash is `2340` -- "apl functional symbol backslash bar".)  since the referenced paper is on interpreters and programming languages, apl fits in that category.  then the `xits` fonts would be relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never seen such a symbol, but you can define it; choose a better name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}

\newcommand{\wrel}{% for ``weird relation''
  \centernot{\mathrel{-}\joinrel\mathrel{-}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
W\wrel X
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes.** I use the fact that TeX doesn't add space between consecutive relation symbols; `\joinrel` is a little negative space that counts as a relation symbol. Thus we get two superimposing minus signs (just like what's done for longer arrows). With `\centernot` we place the `\not` symbol exactly in the middle.

---

A different version using `/` instead of `\not`, so also `\backslash` can be employed instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\centersymbol}[2]{%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{#1#2}\mathpalette\center@symbol{{#1}{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\center@symbol}[2]{%
  \center@@symbol{#1}#2%
}
\newcommand{\center@@symbol}[3]{%
  \ooalign{\hss$#1\m@th#2$\hss\cr\hss$#1\m@th#3$\hss\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\wrel}{\centersymbol{/}{\mathrel{-}\joinrel\mathrel{-}}}
\newcommand{\lerw}{\centersymbol{\backslash}{\mathrel{-}\joinrel\mathrel{-}}}


\begin{document}
\[
W\wrel X \lerw Y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I wanted. And is there a way to also get the other way around? I mean the crossing bar with 135 degree instead of 45?

Answer (score 4):

The package `MnSymbol` defines `\nleftrightline` which looks similar:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
  $W \nleftrightline X$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Usual *caveat*: `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` changes ***all*** math symbols.